# Error while installing mysql on centos 6.7

Tags: mysql, centos6, rpm

```
Error: Package: 2:postfix-2.6.6-6.el6_7.1.x86_64 (@updates)
       Requires: libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit)
       Removing: mysql-libs-5.1.73-5.el6_6.x86_64 (@base)
           libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit)
       Obsoleted By: mysql-community-libs-5.6.29-2.el7.x86_64 (mysql56-community)
           Not found Error: Package: nagios-plugins-mysql-2.0.3-3.el6.x86_64 (@epel)
       Requires: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
       Removing: mysql-libs-5.1.73-5.el6_6.x86_64 (@base)
           libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
       Obsoleted By: mysql-community-libs-5.6.29-2.el7.x86_64 (mysql56-community)
           Not found Error: Package: 2:postfix-2.6.6-6.el6_7.1.x86_64 (@updates)
       Requires: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
       Removing: mysql-libs-5.1.73-5.el6_6.x86_64 (@base)
           libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
       Obsoleted By: mysql-community-libs-5.6.29-2.el7.x86_64 (mysql56-community)
           Not found Error: Package: mysql-community-libs-5.6.29-2.el7.x86_64 (mysql56-community)
       Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17)(64bit)Error: Package: nagios-plugins-mysql-2.0.3-3.el6.x86_64 (@epel)
       Requires: libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit)
       Removing: mysql-libs-5.1.73-5.el6_6.x86_64 (@base)
           libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit)
       Obsoleted By: mysql-community-libs-5.6.29-2.el7.x86_64 (mysql56-community)
           Not found  You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Facing this after

> sudo rpm -Uvh http://repo.mysql.com/mysql-community-release-el7-5.noarch.rpm

Comment: You are trying install package for Centos/RHEL 7 (el7)  on Centos 6

Comment: i removed that package but still same error

Comment: i also installed mysql-devel but same require library are missing

Comment: Do you really need mysql 5.6?

Comment: then what version should i installed i only require mysql > 5.5

Answer (score 1):

> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-yum-repo-quick-guide/en/#repo-qg-yum-fresh-install

By following this link and removing previous by running

```
sudo rpm -e http://repo.mysql.com/mysql-community-release-el7-5.noarch
```

I solved my problem.

Explanation: I was attempting to install from a MySQL repo containing RPMs built for Redhat Enterprise Linux 7 on a RHEL 6 compatible OS.  This lead to various dependency mismatches.   Switching to the correct MySQL repo solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use [IUS repository](https://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/CentOS/6/x86_64/). Because it was especially designed for Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) and CentOS.

```
# wget https://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/IUS-COMMUNITY-GPG-KEY -O /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/IUS-COMMUNITY-GPG-KEY
# rpm --import /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/IUS-COMMUNITY-GPG-KEY
# yum -y install https://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/CentOS/6/x86_64/ius-release-1.0-14.ius.centos6.noarch.rpm
```

But unfortunately there is no easy way to do that. It's  a little bit tricky

```
# wget https://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/CentOS/6/x86_64/mysql56u-libs-5.6.29-1.ius.centos6.x86_64.rpm  
# rpm -ivh --nodeps --force mysql56u-libs-5.6.29-1.ius.centos6.x86_64.rpm
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
   1:mysql56u-libs          ########################################### [100%]

# yum erase mysql-libs
```

After that you can install the mysql server via yum as usually

```
# yum install mysql56u-server.x86_64 mysql56u.x86_64 mysql56u-common.x86_64 mysqlclient16.x86_64
```

The package mysqlclient16 is just replace for mysql-lib for backward compatibility

```
# yum info mysqlclient16
Name        : mysqlclient16
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 5.1.61
Release     : 4.ius.centos6
Size        : 4.1 M
Repo        : ius
Summary     : Backlevel MySQL shared libraries.
URL         : http://www.mysql.com
License     : GPL
Description : This package contains backlevel versions of the MySQL client libraries
            : for use with applications linked against them.  These shared libraries
            : were created using MySQL 5.1.61.
```

If you need mysql 5.5/5.7 just replace mysql56u with mysql55/mysql57u